# How to only render a view when an image inside of it has finished rendering, while showing a rendering indicator?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native

Let's say we have this block of code:

```
  <View>
    <Image
      source={{uri: this.props.image}}
      renderIndicator={() => <SimpleLoader />}
    />
    <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
  </View>
```

It currently shows a rendering animation on the image, but shows the View as well as text, and then eventually renders the image.

I would like to:

1) Have the View itself have `<SimpleLoader />` be displayed while any child item is rendering

2) identify when all the children have finished rendering (or the image, in particular), and then fade the view in.

I was reading around on potentially using a callback with componentDidMount but I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to use [react-native-image-progress](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-image-progress)

One way to do it manually would be to have a loaded: false property in the state initially, then set the [onLoad](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#onload) prop of Image to a function that calls setState({loaded: true}). Then create a function, say showImage() that returns a view of either the image, or the loading indicator depending on whether state.loaded is true or false respectively. In render(), you can then call {this.showImage()}

To fade the image, you can use [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) to animate the opacity of the image inside the style from 0 to 1.

Comment: I'm actually using that package already, and this is no problem to do with the actual image itself. My confusion lies on how the parent component would know that a child component is finished loading, and to only render the parent View when the image is loaded. I can have the image fade in, and show custom renderIndicator.